# VB.net - Dynamically created column with an Image not displaying image in new row in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewimagecolumn

I am building a grid dynamically and want to have a delete image as the last displayed column.

The image displays fine on the row I add, but the new row doesn't have the image.  What am I missing?

When I run the following code I get one row with the image and a second empty row with the 'missing image' icon:

```
Public Class Testing
Private dtData As New DataTable

Private Sub Testing_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LoadMyGrid()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadMyGrid()
    Try


        Dim img As New DataGridViewImageColumn
        Dim inImg As Image = My.Resources.delete
        img.Image = inImg

        dtData.Columns.Add("LanguageId")
        dtData.Columns.Add("Language")
        dtData.Rows.Add(1, "English")

        '--- Load the grid
        With Me.dgv1
            .Columns.Clear()

            .DataSource = dtData
            .Columns(0).Visible = False

            dgv1.Columns.Add(img)
            img.Width = 40
            img.Name = "DELETE"

            .ClearSelection()
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("You hit an error")
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a variable to store the position of the DELETE column

   ```
      Private dgv1DeleteCellIndex as integer = -1
   ```
2. In the LoadGrid, set the dgv1DeleteCellIndex, locate this before the add of the DELETE column

   ```
      dgv1DeleteCellIndex = dgv1.Columns.Count
   ```
3. After the add of the DELETE column loop through the columns and set the cell value to the image

   ```
   For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv1.Rows
      row.Cells(dgv1DeleteCellIndex).Value = My.Resources.delete_16x16
   Next
   ```
4. Update the cell image on RowsAdded event to continue to update the image on any additional new rows added by the user.

   ```
   Private Sub dgv1_RowsAdded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles dgv1.RowsAdded
      If dgv1DeleteCellIndex <= 1 Then Exit Sub

      CType(sender, DataGridView).Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(dgv1DeleteCellIndex).Value = My.Resources.delete_16x16
   End Sub
   ```